# Как отключать предыдущую карту Yandex при показе новой в попап окне по клику?

Tags: javascript, yandex-maps-api

Подключил yandex карты на страницу. Карт несколько. По клику на соответствующую карточку с адресом показывается соответствующая карта со своими координатами в попап окне. Но каждая предыдущая карта остается и в итоге в попап отображаются все карты, которые вызывались по клику ранее.
Примерно понимаю, что необходимо добавить условие в клик.
Прошу помощи.

P.S. Сайт собирается на конструкторе Tilda (если это может быть важным).
P.S.S. Речь идет только о тех карточках, которые находятся под разделителем (фиолетовая линия).

Спасибо

Ссылка на проект: http://test-axpro.tilda.ws/page31234271.html

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
    let buttons = document.querySelectorAll('.map-button');
    let coordinates = [
        [59.907185064216456, 30.32360249999998],
        [56.82273506788084, 60.611883499999976],
        [47.24534707428573, 39.7049965],
        [53.223802571189786, 50.19369900000003],
        [55.04674406964771, 82.95779049999999],
        [54.78367356988649, 56.040994499999876],
        [45.02704307457372, 39.02962499999993],
        [51.685813572274064, 39.17126249999992],
        [43.14411057453034, 131.90757449999995],
        [55.75232856899768, 49.16086099999994],
    ];
    let center = [];

    buttons.forEach((button, index) => {
        button.addEventListener('click', function () {
            center = coordinates[index];

            function init() {
                let mapBranches = new ymaps.Map('mapBranches', {
                    center: center,
                    zoom: 16,
                });

                let placemarkBranches = new ymaps.Placemark(center, {}, {});

                mapBranches.geoObjects.add(placemarkBranches);
            };
            ymaps.ready(init);
        });
    });



});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте такой вариант. Надеюсь смысл будет понятен. Сначала создается карта с меткой, как у вас и было, Только создается она сразу после загрузки DOM. После чего вешаются обработчики на кнопки. Внутри обработчика меняется центр карты и координаты метки. Вы еще можете дополнительно в этом же обработчике изменить зум через метод `setZoom()`.

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
    let buttons = document.querySelectorAll('.map-button');
    let coordinates = [
        [59.907185064216456, 30.32360249999998],
        [56.82273506788084, 60.611883499999976],
        [47.24534707428573, 39.7049965],
        [53.223802571189786, 50.19369900000003],
        [55.04674406964771, 82.95779049999999],
        [54.78367356988649, 56.040994499999876],
        [45.02704307457372, 39.02962499999993],
        [51.685813572274064, 39.17126249999992],
        [43.14411057453034, 131.90757449999995],
        [55.75232856899768, 49.16086099999994],
    ];
    let mapBranches;
    let placemarkBranches;
    ymaps.ready(init);
    
    
    function init() {
      mapBranches = new ymaps.Map('mapBranches', {
        center: coordinates[0],
        zoom: 16,
      });

      placemarkBranches = new ymaps.Placemark(coordinates[0], {}, {});

      mapBranches.geoObjects.add(placemarkBranches);
       buttons.forEach((button, index) => {
          button.addEventListener('click', function () {
              placemarkBranches.geometry.setCoordinates(coordinates[index]);
              mapBranches.setCenter(coordinates[index]);
          });
      });
    };
});
```

Comment: setCoordinates и setCenter это методы специально для карты yandex?

Comment: Все сработало. Спасибо огромное!

Comment: @ЕвгенийКозлов, `setCenter` -- для карты, `setCoordinates` -- для метки

Answer (score 0):

Оберни #mapBranches в ещё один див. Перед добавлением карты удали #mapBranches и создай новый.

Comment: Не проще ли добавить один попап с одной картой и одной меткой, которая будет двигаться по карте при нажатии на конкретную кнопку? Да и зачем оборачивать в еще один див, если карта удаляется через метод `destroy()`?

Comment: @rusgeli Вы бы не могли объяснить как я могу это реализовать?

Comment: @rusgeli у меня как раз один попап

Comment: @rusgeli ссылки нет что именно удалять через дестрой. а обернуть чтоб получить место где пересоздать див.

Comment: @eri Так как я работаю в конструкторе - там уже есть обертка (div). Я не совсем понимаю в каком месте кода удалять #mapBranches, а в каком месте создавать.

Comment: @ЕвгенийКозлов, разместил ответ.

Comment: @eri, так всегда же можно создать переменную вне функции, а в ините присвоить ей ссылку на карту, а потом с ней работать

Comment: но это уже другой ответ)